# RSpec 1.3 without output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I installed RSpec 2 along RSpec 1.3 and since then I think the spec command runs without executing the test file. 
I removed RSpec 2 and am using RSpec 1.3 again.
I type for example "spec spec/views/messages/show.html.erb_spec.rb" on the commandline and the command returns after a few seconds without output. I added errors to the spec file and it seems the file is not read/executed by RSpec.

Does anyone know the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by removing all installed gems and installed the necessary ones again.
(gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs gem uninstall -aIx)

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of changes in rspec2, for one the command `spec` is replaced by `rspec` (i guess that explains your experienced behaviour). Rspec2 is not completely backwards compatible.

You can find a complete list [here](http://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/Upgrade.markdown).

If you are using Rails 3 you will have to use Rspec2.

The transition is not entirely painless, but it should not be too much of a hassle. I started a new project in Rails 3 with Rspec2 and the integration of rails and rspec is now much better. Great :)

Comment: I am still using rspec 1.3 . I just think it has to do with installing rspec 2.0. rspec 1.3 was working before I installed rspec 2.0.